# Tensorflow Estimator and Data Parallelism

Tags: parameters, tensorflow, server, distributed, worker

I am having difficulty to understand how I can use distributed tensorflow for estimator (tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py).

My non-distributed version of implementation is based on learn_runner, experiment, and estimator (github.com/google/seq2seq). That's why I am trying to use ClusterConfig and TF_CONFIG instead of working with ClusterSpec, which is used in the Tensorflow's official tutorial.

I added the following code before the run_config.RunConfig(...) is called:

```
ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")
cluster = {"ps": ps_hosts, "worker": worker_hosts}
os.environ['TF_CONFIG'] = json.dumps({
    'cluster': cluster,
    'task': {
        'type': FLAGS.job_name,
        'index': FLAGS.task_index
    }
})
```

My question is about the parameter server. 
I noticed that the process that I launched with the job name, "ps", also behaves as a worker and does training. I looked into the code ([estimator.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py#L947) and [device_setter.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/device_setter.py#L124)) and it seems that the estimator's implementation actually allows the parameter server to become another worker.

Is it really the case or am I missing something?

One more question is, I tried to use SyncReplicasOptimizer for synchronized distributed learning and it is also pretty difficult to follow the Tensorflow's due to the experiment + estimator wrappers. Is there anybody who has better ideas on this?

I would really appreciate all your help.

Comment: I found the problem. Tensorflow Experiment determines what to schedule depending on the ClusterConfig. Therefore, you shouldn't pass the "--schedule" flag as train or any other value when you use it as a distributed Tensorflow.